# Como redirecionar com o Value e utilizar o texto do Option para o Input do Select?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou com uma dificuldade no Select que é a de usar o Value para complementação de um link e o Select para o Input. Este é o código do Select, como podem ver utilizei o Onchange para levar o Value para o link:

```html
<select class="div-select" name="cidade" id="cidade" onchange="redirect_to.value=redirect_original.value+this.value" required>
    <option disabled selected>Selecione uma cidade</option><!--Opção em branco-->
    <option value="123456789">Guarapuava-PR</option>
    <option value="123456789">Guiratinga-MT</option>
    <option value="123456789">Igrejinha-RS</option>
    <option value="123456789">Joinville-SC</option>
    <option value="123456789">Lajeado-RS</option>
    <option value="123456789">Otacílio Costa-SC</option>
    <option value="123456789">Panambi-RS</option>
    <option value="123456789">Pinhão-PR</option>
    <option value="123456789">Ponta Grossa-PR</option>
    <option value="123456789">Quedas do Iguaçu-PR</option>
    <option value="123456789">Santa Cruz do Sul-RS</option>
    <option value="123456789">Santa Maria-RS</option>
    <option value="123456789">Santo Ângelo-RS</option>  
    <option value="123456789">São Fidélis-RJ</option>
    <option value="123456789">Teixeira de Freitas-BA</option>
    <option value="123456789">Xanxerê-SC</option>
</select>
```

E este é o código que redireciona para abrir o link do WhatsApp:

```html
<input id="redirect_original" type='hidden' name='redirect_original' value='https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=Ol%C3%A1%2C%20tenho%20interesse%20no%20curso%20de%20<?php echo $_GET['curso']; ?>.&phone=55' disabled/>

<input id="redirect_to" type='hidden' name='redirect_to' value='https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=Ol%C3%A1%2C%20tenho%20interesse%20no%20curso%20de%20<?php echo $_GET['curso']; ?>.&phone=55' />
```

Como posso fazer para conseguir colocar o Value no link de redirecionamento para abrir o WhatsApp e o texto do Option para o Input do campo Cidade?

Comment: Não entendi direito, você quer o value de qual elemento e qual o destino desse value? e como assim o select pra um input?

Comment: Os inputs "redirect_original" e "redirect_to" eles fazem o redirecionamento da página, estou buscando uma forma de trazer o value do select pra este input e o que está escrito no option enviar no action do form.

Comment: E esse form estaria aonde? Ele seria parent apenas do select? Apenas dos Inputs ? ou de todos? Tipo dentro do forms estaria o select e os inputs?
Pq vc nao colocou forms ai nos codigos

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Tente usar o cod abaixo.

```js
        function redirect(){
            cidade  =   document.getElementById("cidade").value;
            form    =   document.getElementById("my_form");
            phone   =   "5511988998899";
            text    =   "Ola, Tenho interesse no curso na cidade de "+cidade;
            link    =   "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?";
            n_link  =   link+"text="+text+"&phone&"+phone;
            console.log(n_link);
            form.action=encodeURI(n_link);
            form.submit();
        }
```

```html
    <form id="my_form" target="blank" method="post">
        <select class="div-select" name="cidade" id="cidade" required>
            <option disabled selected>Selecione uma cidade</option><!--Opção em branco-->
            <option value="123456789">Guarapuava-PR</option>
            <option value="123456789">Guiratinga-MT</option>
            <option value="123456789">Igrejinha-RS</option>
            <option value="123456789">Joinville-SC</option>
            <option value="123456789">Lajeado-RS</option>
            <option value="123456789">Otacílio Costa-SC</option>
            <option value="123456789">Panambi-RS</option>
            <option value="123456789">Pinhão-PR</option>
            <option value="123456789">Ponta Grossa-PR</option>
            <option value="123456789">Quedas do Iguaçu-PR</option>
            <option value="123456789">Santa Cruz do Sul-RS</option>
            <option value="123456789">Santa Maria-RS</option>
            <option value="123456789">Santo Ângelo-RS</option>  
            <option value="123456789">São Fidélis-RJ</option>
            <option value="123456789">Teixeira de Freitas-BA</option>
            <option value="123456789">Xanxerê-SC</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    <img src="https://www.maisonchique.com.br/images/whatsapp.png"  width="100px" alt="Iniciar Conversa" onclick="redirect()"></body>
```

quando colocado no sua pagina, ao selecionar a cidade e clicar em iniciar chat, ele vai abrir uma nova guia ja com o link personalizado.